# Fork AOSP source

Tags: android, github, android-source

My team is looking to create our own custom ROM. I would like to base it on AOSP pie. Is there a way to fork or copy the code to GitHub?

I tried just using the Google repo, but it's bigger than my hard drive, so I can't clone it locally to push to GitHub.

We would prefer to base it on a pure Android, not another custom ROM

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can try directly form github:

https://github.com/aosp-mirror

Is mirrored from https://android.googlesource.com/platform/development.git

Hardware requirements:
Your development workstation should meet or exceed these hardware requirements:

- A 64-bit environment is required for Android 2.3.x (Gingerbread) and higher versions, including the master branch. You can compile older versions on 32-bit systems.
- At least 250GB of free disk space to checkout the code and an extra 150GB to build it. If you conduct multiple builds, you will need even more space.
  Note: If you are checking out a mirror you will need more space as full Android Open Source Project (AOSP) mirrors contain all Git repositories that have ever been used.
- If you are running Linux in a virtual machine, you need at least 16GB of RAM/swap.

Comment: This will complicate development greatly though, since you need a lot of repos to create the final build

Comment: Additionally, the [guide](https://source.android.com/setup/build/requirements) explicitly tells you that you even need more space when using a mirror

Comment: The question was:  Is there a way to fork or copy the code to GitHub? and this is a valid answer, of other things should be taken in consideration, the question must be modified, anyway the hardware requirements are a must, so if don't have enough space don't have a project.

Comment: The question explicitly says that the google repo is too big. So using github will get you nowhere as it will be even bigger. So the paragraph with the question is answered, but the answer doesn't fit the constraints given.

Answer (score 1):

Download the source following the guide here:

https://source.android.com/setup/build/downloading

The source is that big, so if your harddrive is too small you won't even be able to use a custom rom for reference.

For reference, the requirements tell you that you need 250GB for the source and 150GB for building. https://source.android.com/setup/build/requirements

Comment: Sadly my VPS has 40gb, and it looks like I need at least 400gb

Comment: If you can, use your local computer. You can set up a VM with VirtualBox for example if you don't use linux.

Comment: um. I don't have one. That's reason #2 I even have a VPS. I'll have to look into buying more storage